# Why "%~fI" parameter expansion is able to "access" not existing drives?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm using the following commands:

```
C:\>for %I in (a: b: c: ">:" "&:") do @rem %~fI
C:\>pushd c:
C:\>set "
```

and the output:

> =&:=&:\
>
> =>:=>:\
>
> =A:=A:\
>
> =B:=B:\
>
> =C:=C:\
>
> ....

As the `=Drive:` variables are storing the last accessed path the corresponding drive , it looks like the `%~fI` expansion somehow accessed not existing drive (which is not possible) . (all parameter expansions create such variables)

Comment: `cd`/`pushd` command **is not necessary** to actually see the =Drive: variables. Try another (even _void_) disk manipulation instead e.g. `>NUL wmic logicaldisk get name`

Comment: BTW, why `set ""|findstr "^="` shows  _non-existing drive_ `=::=::\ ` even from clean `cmd` after restart (along with _expected_ `=C:=C:\…` and `=ExitCode=00000000`)? Please note that `|findstr "^="` is not essential here; it merely narrows output.

Comment: @JosefZ - nobody knows what is `=::` but definitely looks like drive variable. I think it does not exists on Windows 10 machines. The only way to change it's value is with `subst` and it's value can be printed with disabled extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a modifier is used in the `for` replaceable parameter to request a path element, the `for` command (well, a function that retrieves the contents of the variables being read) uses the [`GetFullPathName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to adapt the input string to something that could be handled. This API function (well, some of the OS base functions called by this API) generates the indicated behaviour when a relative path is requested. You can test this c code (sorry, just a quick code test), calling the executable with the ex. `;:` as the first argument.

```c
#define _WIN32_WINNT   0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    DWORD ret;

    LPTSTR lpszVariable; 
    LPTCH lpvEnv; 

    if (argc != 2) return 1;

    if (0 == GetFullPathName( argv[1], BUFFER_SIZE, buffer, NULL )){
        printf ("GetFullPathName failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 2;
    }

    printf("current active directory: %s\r\n", buffer );

    if (NULL == (lpvEnv = GetEnvironmentStrings())) { 
        printf("GetEnvironmentStrings failed (%d)\n", GetLastError()); 
        return 3;
    }

    lpszVariable = (LPTSTR) lpvEnv;
    while (*lpszVariable) {
        if (lpszVariable[0]== '=') printf("%s\n", lpszVariable);
        lpszVariable += lstrlen(lpszVariable) + 1;
    }
    FreeEnvironmentStrings(lpvEnv);
    return 0;
}
```

to get something like

```
D:\>test ;:
current active directory: ;:\
=;:=;:\
=C:=C:\Windows\System32
=D:=D:\
=ExitCode=00000000
```

**EDITED** 2016/12/23

This is for windows 10, but as windows 7 behaves the same it should share the same or similar code.

The output of environment strings to console is handled by `DisplayEnvVariable` function. In older windows versions (checked and XP did it this way) this function calls `GetEnvironmentStrings` to retrive the values, but now (checked and in Vista it was changed) a pointer to a memory area is used. Somehow (sorry, at this moment I can not give this problem more time), it points to a non updated copy of the environment (in this case the updated was not generated by `cmd` command, but from a base `Rtl` function called when resolving the current drive path), generating the observed behaviour.

It is not necessary to execute a `pushd` or `cd` command, any change to the environment or any process creation will result in an update of the pointer.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    echo = before ------------------------------
    set "
    for %%a in ( ";:" ) do rem %%~fa
    echo = after -------------------------------
    set "
    <nul >nul more
    echo = after more --------------------------
    set "
```

You can replace the `more` line with a simple `set "thisIsNotSet="` to get the same result

Comment: Very interesting! But why is a `cd`/`pushd` command necessary to actually see the `=Drive:` variables?

Comment: Exhaustive answer (+1) though the aschipfl's question is still there...

Comment: @aschipfl, Please, see updated answer. I don't know if I am missing something but for me the `cd` or `pushd` are not needed.

Comment: @npocmaka, answer/comments updated. As pointed, maybe I am missing something obvious, but for me there is not need for the `pushd` or `cd`

Comment: @MCND - the pipe creates a new thread/context of the cmd where the jump drives are updated [-:   . Try just with `set "`  .Anyway this is just a detail...

Comment: @npocmaka, as said I was missing something obvious, thank you. At this moment I don't have the debugger at hand. Tomorrow I will check it.

Comment: Looking forward to the results... it's really strange; usually the `=Drive:` variables are created/updated when the respective drive is accessed, seems like `cd`/`pushd` access those (non-existent) drives even with another drive as parameter...

Comment: @aschipfl, the drive is checked when the relative reference is converted to a full path. The `cd` or `pushd` only generate an update of the environment block. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Windows command interpreter tries to get real name of a file or directory on storage media on using an extension like `%~fI` by processing a `QueryDirectory` as it can be seen on using Sysinternals Process Monitor. But the loop variable `I` just holds a string value as defined in set.

From a programmers point of view what should the command interpreter do for example on following code?

```
@echo off
pushd "%SystemRoot%\Temp"
del #abcdefghi.tmp 2>nul
for %%I in (#abcdefghi.tmp) do echo %%~fI
popd
```

There is most likely no file with name `#abcdefghi.tmp` in directory for temporary files for system processes. But output is nevertheless

```
C:\Windows\Temp\#abcdefghi.tmp
```

The Windows command interpreter must built a string as the batch code expects a string. It can't replace `%%~fI` with nothing or with an error message text as this would definitely result in an undefined behavior on further processing of the command lines in the batch file.

Exiting batch processing completely is also no option for Windows command interpreter because the **FOR** loop could be used to check for existence of files.

So the Windows command interpreter makes its best to build from current directory and current string of loop variable a valid file name with path, or just file path, or just file name, ... independent on existence of file/directory or validity of created string.

The command line user respectively writer of batch code has to check for validity or existence and not Windows command interpreter on expanding loop variable reference.

Comment: Yes. But other drives are not in the current directory. try this `for %I in (a: b: c:) do @echo %~fI`  - the drives will be not interpreted like files in the current directory. Looks like it is processing the path differently when the path starts with *single-symbol-semicolon* and  even it puts it to the upper case.

Comment: Agreed, but on a nonexistent item `%~zaI` resolve to nothing. The other modifiers stay on the virtual values. Prepending current drive/path if not present.

Comment: @npocmaka, I'm quite sure that `for` treats singly-symbol-semicolon specially; `a:`, `b:`, `c:` are relative paths pointing to the individual current directories of each respective drive; `for` and `~d`/`~f` do not change the letters to upper-case when you state `a:\ b:\ c:\ `instead, which are absolute paths, so I believe the true (upper-case) drive designation is gathered only in case relative paths are provided, but not for absolute ones...

Comment: @aschipfl  - hmm.. Most probably `for %I in (c:windows) do @echo %~fI` . this is more interesting when you are on a different drive. It takes the value from `=C:` and attach the `windows` at the end. May be that's the reason for additional created drive values. It searches for last jumped drives but there are no such

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two things contributing:

1. A drive letter can actually be every character other than white-spaces, `/` and `\`. Check out the `subst` command, which accepts also an `&`, for example (although it is not listed by `subst`):

   ```
   C:\>subst X: C:\

   C:\>subst ^&: C:\

   C:\>subst
   X:\: => C:\

   C:\>X:

   X:\>^&:

   &:\>
   ```
2. `for` does not access the file system unless it really needs to, which is the case when:

   - wildcards (like `?`, `*`) are used in the set (where the file system needs to be accessed by the `for` command immediately);
   - the `for` reference (`%I`) expansion requires information from the file system:

     - for the modifiers `~s`, `~a`, `~t`, `~z` and `~$ENV:`, information from the file system is required, of course;
     - for the modifiers `~n`, `~x` and `~p`, and also the corresponding parts of `~f`, which is nothing but `~dpnx`, the file system is accessed for case preservation (if the path does not exist, the original case is maintained);
     - for the modifiers `~n`, `~x`, `~p` and `~d`, and also `~f`, the file system needs to be accessed in case a relative path is provided, with or without a dedicated drive specified (for instance, `abc\def`, `D:data`, `P:`), because the current working directory path (of the given drive in case) needs to be determined;

   So the `~d` modifier, and also the corresponding part of `~f`, is handled by pure string manipulation as long as the file system is not accessed according to the aforementioned conditions.

   Simply try your original code but with absolute paths, like `for %I in (a:\ b:\ c:\ ">:\" "&:\") do @rem %~fI`, etc., and you will find that there are no corresponding `=Drive:` variables.

---

#### Summary

Drive letters can literally be almost any characters (see `subst`).
As soon as `for` accesses the file system to search for drives and paths, the accessed drives are recorded in the `=Drive:` variables.

Comment: I've checked if the drives will be listed with `subst`. Note that the example will not work if there's not something like `cd .` or `pushd .` . Or if there's some path besides the drives in for set (it works with `CALL` arguments too).  To me looks like a bug. What I think is going on is the arguments are split in two parts (when the expansion is performed) - one for the drive and one for the path. And the path is written somewhere .

Comment: And when file existence is checked path and the drive are concatenated. And if it does not exist the drive is deleted.But when there's no path but only drive something is not cleared. And when `cd` or `pushd` are used the drive variables are reset.

Comment: Yes, the necessity of `cd` etc. is indeed weird; I have no clue why this is. What do you mean by your [second comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266927/why-fi-parameter-expansion-is-able-to-access-not-existing-drives/41271404#comment69745654_41271404), drive deleted from where? and existence check done by `for`?

Comment: Probably some private array/stack/whatever structure.As the drive is not exactly folder things like `~dp` check if the path exists for a certain drive.I think drives are stored in a different part of memory in this case. And `pushd` and `cd` also have access to it.But without the code this is nothing more than assumption.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the drives aren't really accessed but parsed at an early stage.
A simple for loop can be used to parse nonexistent drives\pathes\files

```
> cd
C:\Users\LotPings

> for %A in (\nonexistent) do @echo %~pnxA
\nonexistent

> for %A in (\nonexistent\a.b) do @echo %~pnxA
\nonexistent\a.b

> for %A in (\nonexistent\a.b) do @echo %~nxA
a.b

> for %A in (\nonexistent\a.b) do @echo %~fA
C:\nonexistent\a.b

> for %A in (^>\nonexistent\a.b) do @echo %~zA
ECHO ist eingeschaltet (ON).

> for %A in (^>\nonexistent\a.b) do @echo %~aA
ECHO ist eingeschaltet (ON).

> for %A in (^>\nonexistent\a.b) do @echo %~fA
C:\Users\LotPings\.\nonexistent\a.b
```

The very last one is quite interesting

Comment: I think the last example can be explained by the [undocumented wild-cards](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6207)...

Comment: the thing the parsing is different when the cmd parses the drives. Check this `for %I in ("z::::sdasd:::") do @echo %~fI`. The drive letter is put to uppercase and it sets slash. But obviously it sets the the drives somewhere in the memory and they are accessed when the `cd` or `push` command is used.