# Remove same file in all folders windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've got approximatively 800 folders, in each of them one file with the same name: index.php

I would like to find a solution where I could remove all the index.php files from all the folders at once, I don't want to open each folder and remove each index.php one by one.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Search this site for *[batch-file] recursively delete files*. You'll find many possible matches that you can alter to meet your requirements.

Comment: Did you happen to notice the /S option with the delete command?

Comment: The /s option is 200% what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really not difficult at all.

```
@echo off
for /R d:\ %%i in (index.php) do echo del "%%~i"
```

set your path where I have `d:\` and once you confirm you are happy with the results it `echo`'s remove the `echo` from the string to actually perform the function.

for more on the for loop, from cmd.exe do `for /?` for full help.

Or without the `for` loop, as mentioned in a comment by **@Squashman**:

```
del /S index.php
```

will delete the file, from the working directory you launch the del command and delete the file in all subdirectories. `/S` is pretty much a search function. `/S` switch also works in `dir /S` to simply search for a file in all subdirectories.

Comment: I'd use `"%%~I"` rather than `%%I` to avoid trouble with paths containing spaces, and I'd add `if exist "%%~I"` in front of the `del` command line, because the `for /R` loop may return also non-existent paths since no wild-card is used -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41271404) for that topic (at § 2.)...

Comment: The /s option is 200% what I was looking for, thanks!